# Cordova 7 - config.xml or package.json?

Tags: cordova, package.json

I've successfully created and released an application on Cordova - so I'm not new to the platform, but it wasn't without its hiccups and frustrations.

With Cordova 7, we now have config.xml and package.json, largely containing the same information.

If I want to change, say the version number, or the title, **which one do I edit** and how do I then update the other file accordingly?

Nothing I've tried seems to work, and it seems rather redundant to have to make the changes twice?

Comment: I recommend you update both. First use ionic commands, if necessary update manually.

Comment: I'm not using Ionic.

Comment: This feature makes no sense. Even running "cordova plugin rm" doesn't properly update these files. I hate that they are automatically editing the dependencies of my package.json. I'm using that for some non-cordova things, and they are polluting it with redundant changes. In addition to this, the same plugin is checked out into node_modules, and into the plugins folder. Now when I remove a plugin, I have to make sure to delete it both places, or those folders remain polluted as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT**:
This is no longer accurate, as of Cordova 9. There is an [issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/issues/1004#issuecomment-510598007) to document this in the docs, which has not been addressed yet. It seems as currently the plan is to migrate away from `config.xml` entirely, however that does not seem to be complete.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55752850/3067153).

---

From what i can read at the [Cordova 7 Release Notes](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html), the `package.json` will always be created to mirror the `config.xml` whenever you run `cordova prepare`, if it does not exist. If a `package.json` does exist, it will take preference (but only for the things defined in it, like plugins and platforms, for other config options `config.xml` will still be used).

So, it might be a solution for you to save your settings in `config.xml`, and always delete the `package.json` before running `cordova prepare`, maybe with a custom npm script.

Comment: I just deleted the package.json file and did a prepare, and it was recreated with the new version number after changing it in config.xml.

However, if I don't delete the file - prepare will not update any details. This seems like an oversight.

What this does highlight to me, is that config.xml should be the priority to keep up to date, which was my main concern with this.

Comment: @AndrewSpode I agree, it is so confusing

Comment: My cordova is getting the app "name" from the config.xml even when the "name" exists on the package.json, but the packages are being read from the package.json, even when I run cordova plugin add, the packages goes only to package.json. So, it's confusing, some info is read from config.xml and others from package.json. Is package.json meant to hold only "plugin packages" references?

Comment: Just delete `package.json` if everything you need is already in `config.xml`. My project has a lot of npm dev packages and npm scripts just mentioned in `package.json`

Answer (score 23):

As an evolution to this question, it looks like Cordova 9.0.0 has decided to stop syncing the config.xml and package.json files now.  So the package.json is the primary location for platform/plugin info, which seems very strange to anyone with significant Cordova experience.

I didn't see this announced anywhere obvious, but stumbled into it while using 9.0.0, and confirmed below:

- https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/03/18/cordova-lib-release-9.0.0.html

> Changes include: GH-750 Remove saving platforms/plugins to config.xml

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/750

Comment: Thank you! Why do they not make these changes clear in their version announcements!?

Comment: I am getting the same experience you described, the package.json looks like to be the "plugins packages" reference manager, while the other info is comming from the XML (app name, version, etc). I think it's because package.json as the name says, it's meant to hold things that have "packages" references, did you guys get the same impression?

Answer (score 3):

For the version number, you can store that in `package.json` and add an npm script named `"version"` that updates `config.xml` accordingly. Then always use `npm version` instead of manually changing the version number.

From the [blog of masimplo](https://masimplo.com/posts/updating-cordova-config-xml-version-using-npm-version/):

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "version": "./bin/update-config-version.sh",
    ...
  },
```

**update-config-version.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG='config.xml'
NEW_VERSION=${npm_package_version}

if [ -e $CONFIG ]; then
    # sed to replace version in config.xml
    sed -i '' "s/\(widget.*version=\"\)\([0-9,.]*\)\"/\1$NEW_VERSION\"/" $CONFIG
    git add $CONFIG
    echo "Updated $CONFIG with version $NEW_VERSION"
else
    echo 'Could not find config.xml'
    exit 1
fi
```

---

There's also [an npm package](https://github.com/gligoran/cordova-set-version). There's always an npm package. Use like so:

```
npm install --save-dev cordova-set-version
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "version": "cordova-set-version --version ${npm_package_version} && git add config.xml",
    ...
  },
```

It doesn't fix most of the duplication, but makes it slightly more bearable. **Edit: cordova-set-version also reformats your `config.xml` and removes all comments from it. I filed [an issue](https://github.com/gligoran/cordova-set-version/issues/133).**

Comment: cordova-set-version library is a life saver :) Thanks!